# Como exibir dados de XML em uma tabela HTML

Tags: jquery, html, xml

Eu gostaria que os dados do XML fossem exibidos em uma tabela comum HTML com `TR` e `TD`, pois com o código que estou usando as informações ficam confusas.

Segue o código que usei:

```
$(function(){
       $.ajax({
        url : "livraria.xml",
        success : function(xml){

            $(xml).find("livro").each(function() {
                $("#tabela").append(
                  "Titulo: " +"<br/>"+
                     "</td></tr>"+  $(this).attr("id") + "-" + "<br/>"+
                                    $(this).text()+"<br>"
                                  );
            });
        },
        error: function(){ 
            alert("Mensagem de erro.");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do XML que estás a receber? o que dá `console.log(typeof xml, xml);` dentro desse `success`?

Comment: Seu código está confuso, estás fazendo `append` na `table` sem criar uma linha (`tr`). Deveria ser algo parecido com isso: `$("#tabela").append("<tr><td>" + $(this).text() + "</td></tr>");`

Comment: @RicardoPontual Queria que na pagina html ficasse mais ou menos como no exemplo do w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_usedfor.asp. Editei o código mais ou menos como você disse:   $("#tabela").append("<tr><td>" + $(this).attr("id") + "<br/>"+
          $(this).text()+"</td></tr>");  mas  o html fica assim fica assim  http://i.imgur.com/SRa44LG.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemplo xml:

[image: XML]

Exemplo codigo:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "ListaMonografias.jsp",
                success: function (xml) {
                    var saida = "";
                    $(xml).find("monografia").each(function () {
                        saida += "<tr>";
                        saida += "<td>" + $(this).find("ano").text() + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + $(this).find("titulo").text() + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + $(this).find("nomeAutor").text() + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + $(this).find("nomeOrientador").text() + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + $(this).find("areaConcentracao").text() + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + $(this).find("local").text() + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td><a href=deletar.jsp?id=" + $(this).find("id").text() + ">Apagar</a><a href=cadastro.jsp?id=" + $(this).find("id").text() + ">&nbsp Editar</a> </td>";
                        saida += "</tr>"
                    });
                    $("#tbody").append(saida);
                    $("#tabela").dataTable();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Processo não concluído");
                }
            });


    <table class="table table-borded table-responsive" id="tabela">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ano</th>
                        <th>Titulo</th>
                        <th>Autor</th>
                        <th>Orientador</th>
                        <th>Area de concentração</th>
                        <th>Local</th>   
                        <th>Ações</th>    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">

                </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado,  funcionou exatamente como eu queria!